# Which of the following compound will undergo rearangement?

Tags: carbocation, rearrangements

**Question**
[image]

**Attempt**
I believe the answer should be B,C and D. In C and D the oxyge(or Nitrogen in D) can rearange by donating lone pair to carbocation.

But the books answer says B. Where am I wrong. Please help.

Comment: In (C) and (D) the carbocation is quite stabilized by conjugation with the lone pairs of O and N respectively. Rearrangement here refers to one caused by a [Wagner–Meerwein rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner–Meerwein_rearrangement) , as resonance is not a form of rearrangement. Only in B does a rearrangement lead to a more stable intermediate with more alpha hydrogens

Comment: @YusufHasan in (b) better will be ring expansion after rearrangement..

Comment: @Zenix I would say that ring expansion isn't absolutely necessary in this case, because 5-membered rings aren't strained a lot as compared to 3 or 4 membered ones. They will only go for 6 membered if there isn't a huge loss in hyperconjugation. Here, ring expansion after rearrangement would lead to a loss of alpha hydrogens